# Changing value in a database with a drag and drop effect with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a drag and drop table that I am using to easily change if someone has made a payment. . Right now the drag and drop part works great. However, I cannot figure out how to give the 3 different table columns 'values'.

I have three different sections:

```
Owes = 1

Partially paid = 2

Paid = 3
```

I have a column in my database where I list this value and it is called payment_id.

So, when an item is dragged from one column to another, I want it to be recognized and a query to be sent to my database to update my table.

```
<table class="paymentTable" id="dragTable">
<?php
//Payment Section

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
 $run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payment_status ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);
    if( $numrows > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $payment_id = $row['payment_id'];
                if($payment_id == 3){
                    $paid_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $paid_name = $row['firstname'];
                }
                if($payment_id == 2){
                    $partially_paid_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $partially_paid_name = $row['firstname'];
                    $partially_paid_amount = $row['payment_amount'];
                }
                if($payment_id == 1){
                     $owes_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $owes_name = $row['firstname'];
                }
 ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="thPayment">Paid</th>
            <th class="thPayment">Partially Paid</th>
            <th class="thPayment">Owes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td class="tdPayment" id="paid">
            <div>
            <?php
                if ($paid_name == true) {
                    echo $paid_name;
                } else {
                    echo "No one has paid";
                }
            ?>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="partially_paid">
            <div>
            <?php 
                if ($partially_paid__name == true) {
                    echo $partially_paid__name . " - " . $partially_paid_amount;
                } else {
                    echo "No one has made a partial payment";
                }
            ?>  
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="owes">
            <div>
            <?php
                if ($owes_name == true) {
                    echo $owes_name;
                } else {
                    echo "Everyone has paid something";
                }
        }       
    }
```

Current JS to make the table draggable.

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#paid, #partially_paid, #owes" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".tdPayment",
      remove: function(e, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var childs = $this.find('div');
        if (childs.length === 0) {
           $this.text("Nothing");
        }
      },
      receive: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
         }).remove();
      },
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

I know this has to be done with AJAX, but I do not know how to assign these values with this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#update_group').on('submit', function (event) { //Do I have to put my table in a form?
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update_payment_status.php',
            type: 'POST', //Not sure what to put here with the drag and drop table
            data: {
            paid: $("#paid").val(3), //Paid
            partially_paid: $("#partially_paid").val(2), //Partially Paid
            owes: $("#owes").val(1), //Owes
        },
        success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $(".success").fadeIn();
                $(".success").show();
                $('.success').html('Payment Status Changed!');
                $('.success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                alert(data);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
            {
              // alert on an http error 
              alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is my first attempt with Ajax so, I'm not sure how to structure this really.

update_payment_status

```
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'error.log');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'core/init.php';

$owes = $_POST['id'];
$partially_paid = $_POST['firstname'];
$owes = $_POST['lastname'];
$payment_username = $row['username'];
$payment_email = $row['email'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE payment_status SET id=? WHERE users_id=?");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Payement Status update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $change_group, $change_group, $approved_id, $approved_id)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Payement Status update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('Payement Status update update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

Source code:

```
 <tr>
                <th class="thPayment">Paid</th>
                <th class="thPayment">Partially Paid</th>
                <th class="thPayment">Owes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
                <td class="tdPayment" id="paid" name="paid">
                <div>
                <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: paid_name in <b>/home4/1/public_html/fdsf.com/userCreator.php</b> on line <b>116</b><br />
No one has paid                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdPayment" id="partially_paid" name="partially_paid">
                <div>
                <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: partially_paid__name in <b>/home4/1/public_html/tre.com/userCreator.php</b> on line <b>127</b><br />
No one has made a partial payment   
                </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdPayment" id="owes" name="owes">
                <div>
                hgfd    




            <tr>
```

Comment: Can you post update_payment_status.php?

Comment: @Hanoncs I added it. I had to make it really quickly. Something like that though.

Comment: It's not perfect, just just to get you an idea. The part that is really getting me is how to structure it based on how I can get the data from Ajax.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please reword your question? Its hard to figure out what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I want to know how when a user is dragged to a different section. ie: Owes to Paid, How I can change payment_id to 3. Then I need to be sure AJAX recognizes the change of the table, so it can send that value to my php file to update.

Comment: Please post source html for client side problems. People shouldn't have to be php parsers to try to figure out the DOM structure. Since most of this revolves around drag/drop 90% of the issue is client side and copying source from browser is a simple task

Comment: `data:{ paid: $("#paid").val(3)...` will set the value to 3 and return jQuery which will fail in the post. `val()` with no parameters is the getter

Comment: I added the source code. Don't mind the errors,. Is that what you are looking for?